# How to throw an object Unity3d platform? This 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is a platform revolving around its own axis (it works). We need to make sure that when you change the angle of the object platform rolled (it works), and the sudden change in the direction of rotation of the object throws. In LibGdx (+ Box2d + Scene2d) I did:

```
  @Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact) { // It begins cooperation
    Body a = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
    Body b = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();

    if ((BodyUtils.bodyIsRunner(a) && BodyUtils.bodyIsGround(b)) ||
            (BodyUtils.bodyIsGround(a) && BodyUtils.bodyIsRunner(b))) {

        character.charStartJump(); // below
    }

}
```

The essence of the following code: the array position values ​​are fed along the axis Y, and each value is compared with the last penultimate ( in order to determine the movement begins from the bottom up, ie begins to accumulate value only if the character is moving upwards)

```
 public void charStartJump() {
    impulse_Y.add(getBody().getPosition().y);
    if (impulse_Y.size() <= 1) {
        impulse_Y_start_point = impulse_Y.get(impulse_Y.size() - 1);
    } else if (impulse_Y.size() > 1) {
        if (impulse_Y.get(impulse_Y.size() - 1) <= impulse_Y.get(impulse_Y.size() - 2))
            impulse_Y_start_point = impulse_Y.get(impulse_Y.size() - 1);
        else
            impulse_Y_start_point = impulse_Y.get(impulse_Y.size() - 1) - impulse_Y_start_point;
    }


}

@Override
public void endContact(Contact contact) { // end collaboration
    Body a = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
    Body b = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();

    if ((BodyUtils.bodyIsRunner(a) && BodyUtils.bodyIsGround(b)) ||
            (BodyUtils.bodyIsGround(a) && BodyUtils.bodyIsRunner(b))) {
        character.charJump(); // below
    }

}

 public void charJump() {

// applied to the body with the direction of the momentum 0 on the X axis , take the momentum gained by Y.
// The pulse is applied to the center of the body . true - the object is not sleeping (isAweking = true)
        body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, impulse_Y_start_point*1.2f), body.getWorldCenter(), true);
        impulse_Y.clear(); 
    impulse_Y.trimToSize(); // in these two lines of cleanse arrayList charStartJump ()
}
```

Upd: picture
[image]

Comment: I may be speaking only for myself, but I cannot clearly decipher your question from what you have written. Could you please add additional details to your question about what you're trying to achieve, and how your current approach fails to meet your requirements? (Additional clarification would also be appreciated - eg. What does `the sudden change in the direction of rotation of the object throws` mean?)

Comment: Upd: picture <http://s32.postimg.org/tv0s14dut/Example.png>

Comment: I'm not sure I understand clearly. But. What's wrong with Unity's physics? Why don't you use that? Based on the picture I wouldn't say the goal is something special or "anti-physics". Unity should do exactly what you describe, based on Rigidbody/gravity/drag/etc settings you define.

Comment: I really like your question, however, does the default physic2d work?